# SLURM Job Array output file in command

Tags: hpc, slurm

I have a command list like this

```
bedtools intersect -a BED1 -b BED2 >BED1_BED2_overlaps.txt
...
```

with over 100 files.

Here is the header for my job submission

```
#SBATCH -t 0-08:00
#SBATCH --job-name=JACCARD_DNase
#SBATCH -o /oasis/scratch/XXX/XXX/temp_project/logs/JACCARD_DNase_%a_out
#SBATCH -e /oasis/scratch/XXX/XXX/temp_project/logs/JACCARD_DNase_%a_err
#SBATCH --array=1-406%50
```

When I submit the job I get this error

```
Error: Unable to open file >BED1_BED2_overlaps.txt Exiting.
```

I tried to pipe an echo command like this

```
bedtools intersect -a BED1 -b  BED2 | echo "BED1 BED2"
```

And I got

```
Error: Unable to open file |. Exiting.
```

So what gives? How can I submit array jobs with Bash syntax like `>` output and `|` pipes?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) ; your submission script should start with

```
#! /bin/bash
```

or any other shell you like.